# How to use pseudo selectors before::after in tailwindcss?

Tags: css-selectors, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

I have hard time figuring this out on Youtube and Google. Seems like this is the only place where I will get the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currrently tailwindcss doesn't have Pseudo Elements utilities like before::after.
For that you need to install the pseudo element plugin

```
 # for NPM
 npm install tailwindcss-pseudo-elements --save-dev

# for Yarn
yarn add tailwindcss-pseudo-elements -D
```

Then you need to add some lines in your tailwind.config.js file,
for that refer [this](https://smarative.com/blog/learn-pseudo-with-tailwind-css)

Comment: Tailwind added support for pseudo-elements in v3. [Documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#pseudo-elements).